# Does calculating the length of a list at the beginning of a while loop make it slower?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, loops, time-complexity

I know a while loop will have O(n) time complexity, but if I understand correctly, it takes one pass through the data to calculate the length of the data, which is the stopping point in this case (Python):

```
# list x
# i = 0
while i < length(x):
   # Code here...
   i += 1
```

So, would this end up being more than one actual pass through the data after the loop has fully executed?

Alternatively, would something like this be faster in runtime, since we don't have to calculate the length of the list at the beginning of the loop?:

```
# list x
# i = 0
while(1):
   try:
      x[i]
   except:
      break
   # Code here...
   i += 1
```

Obviously both are O(n) time complexity, but is the second example overall faster?

Comment: This is very language/compiler/platform/etc specific and you haven't specified the language. The first snippet is not valid python. But if your question is about python, then no. Taking the `len` of a list in python is a constant operation.

Comment: Getting the length of a `list` in Python is an O(1) operation. You may be thinking of the C language `strlen` function, which does take O(n).

Comment: @user3386109: Python's (default) `len` function executes in O(1) but it's not as fast as keeping the length in a local variable. Although directly iterating over the list with a `for` loop is almost always better. (I know you know that stuff. I'm talking to the gallery.)

Comment: If you want indexes as you iterate through a list in python, you write `for i, v in enumerate(x):` Neither of the two ways you list are idiomatic code (especially the second).